# How to create a function that outputs a number on typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a very basic question because I am a noob at typescript...

I have the following function that is working correctly:

```
getLatestSystemMessage(thread: Thread): string {
        const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);

        let content = '';

        if (message) {
            switch (message.type) {
                case 1: 'Please choose' break
                case 2: 'Selected' break }}}
```

Now I want to create another function as I am trying to create an NgSwitch therefore I want to write and `[ngSwitch]="messageType(thread)"` `*ngSwitchCase=2` in my component.html. The number that is outputted should be the the `message.type`. So far I have this, is this correct?

```
    getMessageType(thread: Thread): number {
    const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);
    return message.type;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `ngSwitch` directive to match a number in your expression, you'd need to return the type property on the resulting message object.

For example:

```
messageType(thread: Thread): any {
    const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);
    
    if (message !== undefined) {
        return message.type;
    }
    // return a reasonable default
}
```

Comment: Ok I fixed the error but this is still not working even though it looks correct...

Comment: `TypeError: _co.messageType is not a function` is what I am seeing..